# How to access URL of guest machine from host machine on Vagrant?

Tags: python, vagrant, virtualbox, urllib2

I'm running a Flask application where the basic layout is:

```
def run_period():
    urllib2.urlopen('http://10.0.2.15:8080/foo')

@app.route('/')
def mainpage():
    run_period()

@app.route('/foo')
def entertainment():
    # do something
```

My vagrant file is configured as follows:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "pg_config.sh"
  # config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
end
```

I did an `ifconfig` in my VM to get the IP address which I passed in `urlopen()`.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4b:d4:80
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4b:d480/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1578 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:219636 (219.6 KB)  TX bytes:437048 (437.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:218049 (218.0 KB)  TX bytes:218049 (218.0 KB)
```

But I can't open `http://10.0.2.15:8080/` on my host (windows) machine.

Comment: why do you need to call `urllib2.urlopen` do not map your app with the static IP, vagrant uses `10.0.2.15` as the NAT address to communicate (ssh) with the VM

Comment: I wanted to run the `/foo` handler function at periodic intervals of time. Since it can't be passed as a parameter into `threading.Timer`, I thought maybe I could make a normal function, call the handler from inside it and make the normal function run periodically.
Should I change the IP of my VM?